# Rails devise create a related object after new user is created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Using Rails 4.1 and Devise 3.0.3, how can I create an associated object on User when User is instantiated and connect the two?

```
def User
  has_one :case
end
def Case
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In this case, User is set up with devise.

What I'd like to do is instantiate an object like so:

```
  @case = Case.new
  current_user.case = @case
```

or

```
  current_user.case << @case
```

How can I execute this code when a request is made to "registrations#new"?

Comment: Glad I could help Adam!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would implement this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  before_action :create_case, only: [:new, :create]

  def create_case
    case = Case.create
    self.case = case.id
    # Maybe check if profile gets created and raise an error 
    #  or provide some kind of error handling
  end
end
```

Comment: How does this work? There's no before_action in ActiveRecord, isn't before_action a method available in controller?

Answer (score 1):

Override `create` action of [Devise::RegistrationsController](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb) and pass a block to it:

```
# app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb

class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super do
        resource.case = Case.new
        resource.save
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If I do this do I have to re-implement all other functionality in the Devise RegistrationsController?

Comment: No you don't. Because it's extending `Devise::RegistrationsController`. Or you can just simply do `def new super end`.

Comment: Is resource a Devise variable I should use? Or did you just use that as an example?

Comment: `resource` is the saved user. You do not need to change anything.

Comment: Where do you learn about these conventions? I love ruby, rails, etc, but unlike Java or other statically typed languages where I can see the entire API available to me within my IDE, interacting with these ruby gems sometimes feels like stabbing in the dark.

Comment: Read the code (it's Ruby - so it's nice to read actually, lol)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [create](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class) method inside your User model. Something similar like this:

```
def self.create(username, email, pass)
  user = User.new(:username => username, :email => email, :password => pass)
  user.case = Case.new
  return user if user.save
end
```

Comment: How does devise/activerecord know to execute this method if it's simply defined and not being called anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to override `Devise::RegistrationsController#create` and in the create action you have to take `resource` and do something like this `resource.build_case`

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_one-association-reference